# Multihop ssh tunnel/proxy

Tags: networking, ssh, proxy, tunnel

I am trying to set up an ssh tunnel/proxy configuration to enable me to reach a private API so that I can test it.

The API is hosted in AWS API Gateway and is configured by design to be reachable only from private subnets where our lambdas are deployed. For testing purposes, I have an EC2 (Amazon Linux 2023) in this subnet and a bastion/jump host EC2 in a public subnet. Via this mechanism I can access the private API by ssh’ing (to the private host via the bastion), and using curl.

Now I need to extend this configuration so that I can reach the API from my local machine via HTTP (I need to be able to access it using Python requests client, but this is irrelevant - let’s just say it’s something that understands proxies and can be persuaded in this configuration to ignore SSL cert errors). I figure I need to set up a proxy on the private EC2 (I am confident that access to this is restricted by SG rules to people coming from whitelisted IPs) and then ssh tunnelling to this from my local.

However, I'm confused by the various options for doing this via a single ssh command. I know that all the parts in the diagram are configured correctly, but I can't figure out an ssh command to run locally to make it work.

My local system is a MacBook and has this ssh:

```
$ ssh -V
OpenSSH_8.6p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

[image: Existing configuration]